# Will I miss anything if I play Ys VIII: Lacrimosa of Dana without playing previous games?

Tags: ys

So I was going to download Ys VIII Lacrimosa of Dana. But before doing so I realized its VIII. Will I miss many important references if I start from Ys VIII directly without playing the previous titles?

Comment: Given the context, this seems better suited for [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a role-playing game rather than an anime or manga.

Comment: "Can I/Should I" questions are generally frowned upon because it's considered as personal advice, which usually there's no real answer (because the answer is always: **yes you can, but...**). You could instead directly ask "Will I miss many important references if I start from *Ys VIII* directly without playing the previous titles?"

Comment: @AkiTanaka While correct, it is a minor change that is easy to edit in yourself (I already did in fact).

Comment: @kuwaly really late to the party with this but we do allow for lore question in japanese games. more so that the [first 2 games of the Ys Series were made into anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ys_(anime))

Comment: this should have been marked as off topic a while back.